# Referencing label with conditional page info

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, varioref

I would like to have an easy way to reference a label and if that label is not on the current page then its page should be printed in the reference like "See example 2.3 (p.4)". I tried  the `varioref` and the `cleveref` packages but their text output using `\vref` or `\cref` is too verbose for me. I couldn't find anything in the documentation to just print (p.4) instead. Or is there another alternative?

Comment: Why couldn't you "find anything in the documentation"? Where did you look? Section 3 "Customization" of varioref.pdf has all the details.

Comment: I saw that but couldn't figure out that this section with its non-existing examples is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using babel you can change the printed reference with package `varioref` as shown in the following MWE for German language.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}% article

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} 

\addto{\extrasngerman}{% addto only with babel  <===============
  \renewcommand{\reftextfaceafter}[1]{(Seite~\pageref{#1})}
  \renewcommand{\reftextfacebefore}[1]{(Seite~\pageref{#1})}
  \renewcommand{\reftextafter}[1]{(Seite~\pageref{#1})}
  \renewcommand{\reftextbefore}[1]{(Seite~\pageref{#1})}
  \renewcommand{\reftextcurrent}[1]{(Seite~\pageref{#1})}
  \renewcommand{\reftextfaraway}[1]{(Seite~\pageref{#1})}
}


\begin{document}

\section{Abschnitt 1}
\label{sec:Test}

Und der erste Verweis auf Abschnitt~\vref{sec:Test}. %  <===============

\Blinddocument

Und der Verweis auf Abschnitt~\vref{sec:Test}.       %  <===============

\end{document}
```

The macro `\addto{\extrasngerman}` adds the new meanings for language `ngerman`. If you use another language change `ngerman` to your language.

Change `(Seite~\pageref{#1})` to that you need, for example `(p.~\pageref{#1})`.

**Edit:**

The KOMA-Script macro `\newcaptionname{ngerman}{...}` is not able to handle a third argument (for `\pageref{#1}`) so you can't use it here.

Comment: Perfect. One thing that is strange is that i get errors like "Extra \else." when I keep using cleveref.

Comment: @user764754 errors might be due to the order you load packages (or not all of them up-to-date): hyperref, babel and cleveref all overwrite some of the varioref definitions.

Answer (score 6):

If you use varioref all the fixed texts are in easily changable macros, for example the package has

```
    \def\reftextfaraway#1{on page~\pageref{#1}}%
```

so you can have

```
    \renewcommand\reftextfaraway[1]{p.~\pageref{#1}}%
```

and similarly for any other texts it produces.

Comment: Thanks! What worked for me was \addto\extrasngerman{\renewcommand{\reftextfaraway}[1]{(p.\pageref{#1})}}

Comment: @user764754 this is needed because Babel is used. All of that is documented in varioref.pdf (section 3).